# Continuity with $f(x)=f(x+1)$ $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$. Is there $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=f(x+\sqrt{2})$?

Tags: continuity, upper-lower-bounds, extreme-value-theorem

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continous with $f(x)=f(x+1)$ $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$. Show there exists $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=f(x+\sqrt{2})$.

**My question is, do we even need $f(x)=f(x+1)$ $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ to show this, or is is sufficient, that f is bounded?** What happens if $f$ is monotonous?

I posted a sketch for the proof of the original/task problem below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $\arctan x$ is bounded and continuous, but the $x$ the problem asks for does not exist, so the periodicity assumption is indeed important.

Comment: It doesn't work, because $arctan$ is monotone, right? So I would need, both the assumption, that f is bounded, and not monotone. And then, I could maybe proof it as I did below?

Comment: No that doesn't work. Consider $\delta(x)$ with $\delta(-0.1)=0, \delta(0)=0.1, \delta(0.1)=0$ and it's constant=$0$ before the first and after the last given point, and linear in between the given 3 points (a small "hat" function). You can see that $f(x)=\arctan(x)+\delta(x)$ is not monotone, as $f(0)=0.1, f(0.1)=\arctan(0.1) < 0.1=f(0)$. Still, there is no point with $f(x)=f(x+\sqrt{2})$. Because if there was, either $x$ or $x+\sqrt{2}$ would have to be in the "changed from arctan" interval $[-0.1,0.1]$. Since $f(\sqrt{2}-0.1)\approx 0.92$, this can't be.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach the proof for the original problem/task:

First consider $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$. Since $f$ is continuos, we can apply the extreme value theorem. Thus, there exists $a:= \min_{x\in [0,1]}$ and $b:=\max_{x\in [0,1]}$.

Now we can use $f(x)=f(x+1)$ $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$. As a result there cannot exists $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$ with $f(\xi)<f(a)$ or $f(\xi)>f(a)$. *Has anyone an idea how this can be shown rigorously?* As a consequence $a$ is a global minimum and $b$ is a global maximum.

Let $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R},\; g(x)=f(x+\sqrt{2})-f(x) $.

Then we have $g(a)=f(a+\sqrt{2})-f(a)\geq 0$, and $g(b)=f(b+\sqrt{2})-f(b)\leq 0$. Because $a$ is a global minimum and $b$ is a global maximum of $f$.

If $g(a)=0$ or $g(b)=0$ we are done. Else, by the intermediate value theorem, there exists $x \in (a, b)$, such that $g(x)=0$.

Why are we done? Because  $g(x)=0 \iff f(x+\sqrt{2})- f(x)=0 \iff f(x)=f(x+\sqrt{2})$.

Answer (score 0):

You can note that if you have $\xi\in\mathbb{R}$, you have $f(\xi)=f(\xi-\lfloor \xi\rfloor) $ and you have $\xi-\lfloor\xi\rfloor \in [0,1]$, so you get that the maximum and the minimum are global

Comment: Thanks a lot, that looks clean.